# How to create a simple button with javascript to call a zend action in zend framework?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, zend-framework

I want to create a simple javascript button that will be disabled once the current user clicked it.

I have a zend framework action that I d like to be called once the user clicks it but disabled the button for ever, if the current user already clicked it.

My zend framework action is something like this: `public function addvisitedlocationAction()
    {

```
    $locationID = $this->_getParam('location_id');
    echo "Location ID: " . $locationID; 
    $visited = 1;
    $memberID = $this->view->identity;
    $email= $memberID->email;   

    $currentUser = Model_DbTable_Members::getMember($email); 
    $memberID2 = $currentUser['id'];
    echo '<br>Current Member id: ' . $memberID2;
    //$profile = Model_DbTable_Members::findMembersProfile($email);
    $this->view->currentMember = $currentUser; 
    //$this->view->theProfile = $profile; 
    $visitedModel = new Model_DbTable_MembersVisitedLocations();
    $visitedModel->addMemberVisitedLocation($memberID2, $locationID,$visited);

    return $this->_redirect('/restaurant/viewrestaurantlocationprofile/location_id/'. $locationID);
}//end of addvisitedLocation;`
```

I want to call this once the javascript button is clicked and disable the button for ever for that user.

My problem is I am familiar with javascript but don't really know where to start from. 
I have a simple image that I can use as a button.
My aim is to call that action without redirecting the page and disable the button for the current user.

Any suggestions how I can achieve that?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't do simple things with Zend Framework...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to call another page without reloading or redirecting the user then you'd need to use AJAX.

Using jQuery, you can do it like this:

```
function whatever()
{
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "/my/action/to/call",
       data: "mydataitem="+dataitem,
       success: function(html, msg){
           //do something on success
       }
     }); 
}
```

This will allow you to send data to another Zend Action, which can then process your request.

To disable the button, you can just do `$('#myidofbuttonOrimage').attr('disabled', 'disabled');`

If you're using a library such as jQuery, this is very simple, otherwise here's some links that may help you.

Hope this helps

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

Comment: And you can called whatever() using an onclick on the image that you want to be your link. If you're using an image, then you can't add a disabled attribute, you'd need to either remove the link using javascript, or set further clicks to "preventdefault" - see http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/